# Limit the number of parse results

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

How do I limit the number of parse results returned. I tried this method like parse doc says but it still returns all objects ~78. Help please.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"posts"];

    [query whereKey:@"school_ID" equalTo:currentUser[@"school_ID"]];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    query.limit = 5;


    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your trying to limit how many objects are fetched then you can set a limit to your query. However, PQTVC uses objectPerPage. So If you trying to limit the number of fetched results you will have to set a limit on the query itself otherwise PFQTVC will override your limit value with pagination enabled

So. I think based off your question you simply want to limit the number of results displayed in the PFQTVC. That's what objectsPerPage is for. This by default is set to 100.

An example:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    self.objectsPerPage = 5;
}
```

[PFQTVC properties](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html)

**EDIT**

I just reread your question but still answered it indirectly, sorry typing from iPhone and autocorrect is kicking my butt. PFQTVC overrides limit requests when pagination is enabled. Set paginationEnabled to NO in your init method and your query.limit = 5; request in (PFQuery) queryForTable will function properly

Comment: Thanks for your response and it seemed to have done the trick. One thing I would add to your answer though is, for those that have the same problem, make sure you are using `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
` and not `-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style` as it will never be called if you are using PFQTVC

Comment: @user3268402 very true. Lapse of memory there (pun intended) glad your up and running. Happy coding -

Answer (score 0):

Code seems fine. I think the problem is caused by your cache policy. Try to set it to `kPFCachePolicyIgnoreCache`.